# A healthy number sequence

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence

What should b the missing number?

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, ?, 12

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing number is:

> 9

Because these numbers are those which are also...

> **B vitamins** when prefixed with 'B'! This explains the 'healthy' title (vitamins are needed for good health) and the use of 'b' rather than 'be' in the text (it's a hint, not a typo!).
>
>  The [B vitamins](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_vitamins) are:
>
>  B1 Thiamine
>  B2 Riboflavin
>  B3 Niacin
>  B5 Pantothenic acid
>  B6 Pyridoxine
>  B7 Biotin
>  **B9 Folate**
>  B12 Cobalamins
>
>  B9 is missing in the original sequence.

Comment: Correct and well done on spotting the hints!

Comment: Personally I was surprised to learn that some of the original numbers were removed.